# WSDL- dot.net API always shows validation error for my PHP code . Please suggest another method

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

API docs says following code is for the registration but our code always showing validation error only. Suggest me any other method based on these data. I hope there is validation error , but client not ready to give dotnet code or other API details

Authentication key is providing here like `tokenKey`, `domainCode`, etc.

```
class PartnerIdentityfier_DataContracts
{
    public $mDomainCode;
    public $mTokenKey;
    public $mUserIPAddress;
}
```

Registration data is sent to code via this class

```
class clsRegistration_DataContracts
{
    public $mEmailId;
    public $mUPassword;
    public $mLoginDateTime;
    public $mTitle;
    public $mFirstName;
    public $LastName;
    public $Mobile;
    public $LandLine;
    public $Address1;
    public $Address2;
    public $Address3;
    public $Pincode;
    public $CityName;
    public $StateName;
    public $City_Customer;
    public $Landmark;
    public $DOB;
    public $mGender;
    public $mCompanyName;
    public $AlternateEmailid;
    public $mPartnerIdentity;
}
```

Setting values to class variables

```
$contact = new PartnerIdentityfier_DataContracts();
$contact->mDomainCode="XDUIDVP0006";
$contact->mTokenKey="8IJUOX-P4ZPX-LNDAA-CWXHB-PJMTA-9SUD*-WQJ9";
$contact->mUserIPAddress=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; 

$xcv=new clsRegistration_DataContracts();       
$xcv->mEmailId="kiran@nex.in";
$xcv->mUPassword="1234567INq";
$xcv->mLoginDateTime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$xcv->mTitle="Mr";
$xcv->mFirstName="kiran";
$xcv->LastName="deepu";
$xcv->Mobile="8807541983";
$xcv->LandLine="8807541983";
$xcv->Address1="Chennai";
$xcv->Address2="Chennai";
$xcv->Address3="Chennai";
$xcv->Pincode="600017";
$xcv->CityName="Chennai";
$xcv->StateName="TamilNadu";
$xcv->City_Customer="Chennai";
$xcv->Landmark="Chennai";
$xcv->DOB="1992-01-04 18:12:00";
$xcv->mGender="M";
$xcv->mCompanyName="nokia";
$xcv->AlternateEmailid="damuslm@gmail.com";
$xcv->mPartnerIdentity=$contact; ``

//here we are using soapclient method to get data from the server

$client = new SoapClient('http://407.129.110.150:8087/DVPService?wsdl');

// Registration function is POSTUserRegistration . we send all the data to  this function. But we hope the sending data is not prpoerly reached here . or some other issue in sending data that my doubt right now . can you suggest any other method to sent these datas to dotnet server.        
$response = $client->POSTUserRegistration($xcv);
print_r($response);
```